# Is there an established name for bi-module morphisms that swap the module structures?

Tags: terminology, modules, bimodules

Let $P,Q$ denote two $R$-bimodules where $R$ is a ring, for my purposes commutative. I'll write the left $R$-module structure by multiplication on the left and analogously for the right structure.

Is there an established name for a map $\phi :P\to Q$ that respects addition and satisfies 
\begin{equation}
\phi(r_1 p r_2)=r_2\phi(p)r_1
\end{equation}
for all $r_1,r_2\in R$, $p\in P$?

If not, are there any objections to calling it a *contravariant $R$-bilinear* map?

Comment: I would call simply it a bimodule homomorphism $P\to Q^{op}$ where $Q^{op}$ is the bimodule where the right- and left-module-structure are swapped.